# Gulp: watch HTML files, do some task, then browserSync.reload

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, browser-sync

Our HTML files are 'assembled' from a few template/partial HTML files. Now I want Gulp to be able to do these tasks **sequentially**:

1. Watch 'template' HTML files
2. If there is any update, run the tasks `pages`
3. Then, refresh the webpage.

I read through this tutorial: https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/. But it simply watches the HTML files and reload. I tried this:

```
gulp.watch([
    path.join(dpw.src.commonLayouts, 'layout.html'),
    dpw.src.commonPages + "/**/*.html",
    dpw.src.sitePages + "/**/*.html"
], ['pages']).on("change", browserSync.reload);
```

The web page will be reloaded automatically. And the task `pages` is run.

However, the refreshed page is always one version behind. It means, if I change some text from "12" to be "123", the page is refreshed but the text is "12". Then I change to "1234", the page is refreshed to be "123"...

I am using `Gulp` 3.9.0 and `browser-sync` 2.11.1.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: use the `run-sequence` plugin.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MatthewRath, I implemented it using [`runSequence`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence):

```
gulp.task('pages-watch', function () {
    runSequence('pages', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.watch([
    path.join(dpw.src.commonLayouts, 'layout.html'),
    dpw.src.commonPages + "/**/*.html",
    dpw.src.sitePages + "/**/*.html"
], ['pages-watch']);
```

But it introduces a new task, which is a bit tedious.